# multiple log regression models ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following example, I follow on from the following [link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Statistical_analysis/Logistic_regression/), in which we learn the basic to creating a log regression model.

```
data(mtcars)
dat <- subset(mtcars, select=c(mpg, am, vs))
logr_vm <- glm(vs ~ mpg, data=dat, family=binomial)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=mpg, y=vs)) + geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"), se=T) + 
  theme_bw()
```

Now I want to create a second log model where we predict a new outcome `vs2`.
How can I use `ggplot2` to show the two models with different colours?

```
dat$vs2 <- with(dat, ifelse(mpg > 20, 1, vs))
```

so that the secondary log model is ....

```
logr_vm2 <- glm(vs2 ~ mpg, data=dat, family=binomial)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When fitting the models with `ggplot` itself, and you only have a few models, you can easily add a legend by manually mapping a model name to colors inside `aes`. The rest will then be taken care of.

Addionally, I use `geom_count` instead of `geom_point` to show that we have overlapping values here, and add some colors to show your different categories:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = mpg)) + 
  geom_count(aes(y = vs, col = mpg > 20), alpha = 0.3) + 
  stat_smooth(aes(y = vs, fill = 'm1'), col = 'black',
              method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial")) + 
  stat_smooth(aes(y = vs2, fill = 'm2'), col = 'black', 
              method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial")) +
  scale_size_area() +
  scale_color_discrete(h.start = 90) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]